# Webscraping using cURL

Tags: php, web-scraping, curl

i want to webscrape a certain thing of a website. I got it to work last time but now it seems the website has been updated, the previus source list looked like this

```
 <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="rankRow"
                                                                       data-rankkey="25">
                                                                                Averages
                                                                        </a>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td class="page_speed_602217763">
                                                                        82.84                                                                        </td>
```

Where i want the number 82,84. I found the solution last time to be

```
      $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $Player1Link);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $curlresult = curl_exec($curl);

  $html= $curlresult;
  $domd = new DOMDocument();
  @$domd->loadHTML($html);
  $xp = new DOMXPath($domd);
  $P1Avg = $xp->query("//td[contains(@class, 'page_speed_')]")->item(0)->textContent;
  $P1Avg = trim($P1Avg);
```

Now the website has been updated and the source list looks like this

```
                                                                    <td><a 

href="javascript:void(0)" class="rankRow"
                                                                               data-rankkey="25">
                                                                                        Averages
                                                                                </a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align:right;'">
                                                                                89.61                                                                        </td>
```

Where i still want the number (Average) in this case 89,61. How would i go about making the changes?
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Given there are probably many `td` elements with `style="text-align:right;'"` you'll probably need more context to find that cell

Comment: actually the style="text-align:right;'" looks pretty much to only be where i need it

Comment: Then you should be able to just replace `//td[contains(@class, 'page_speed_')]` with `//td[contains(@style, 'text-align:right')]`

Comment: thank you so much, that worked, i think when i tried it before i took the "" with so it became @style, '"text-align:right')]"

Comment: I guess you have two working solutions then! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might make use of the `class="rankRow"` in the anchor of the preceding `td`

```
//td/a[@class='rankRow']/parent::td/following-sibling::td[1]
```

For the given html in the question:

```
$html=<<<HTML
<td><a 

href="javascript:void(0)" class="rankRow"
                                                                               data-rankkey="25">
                                                                                        Averages
                                                                                </a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align:right;'">
                                                                                89.61                                                                        </td>
HTML;

$domd = new DOMDocument();
@$domd->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($domd);
$P1Avg = $xp->query("//td/a[@class='rankRow']/parent::td/following-sibling::td[1]")->item(0)->textContent;
$P1Avg = trim($P1Avg);
echo $P1Avg;
```

Output

```
89.61
```